# How do I know when someone has shared my link on social media

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, share, social-networking

On my website I want to make certain features available after a person has shared my link on Facebook or Twitter, etc. So the idea is to ask the visitor to share my link. Then after they share the link, to create a cookie for them. Then I would check said cookie to determine if they have access.

My question is **how do I know the person has shared?** So say the person clicks on the Facebook button. Then possibly he has to login into Facebook. After the actual sharing is done, what kind of feedback do I get so that I can go create the cookie?

If the whole thing can be done in javascript and html that would be great, but in case the server has to be involved, I am using python. Again, I know how to write my code about setting cookie and about asking someone to share on social network. The one thing I don't know is **how do I get the feedback that the sharing actually took place?**

Comment: Your site doesn't use facebook/twitter login, which gives you permissions to see what they have done? If not, then you should not be able to tell; how would you know which user is which, even if someone shared it?

Comment: The cookie is a front-end cookie, that is created and stored using javascript. I don't really need to track a user but rather a computer. The cookie expires every 24 hour. I just need to know that the sharing took place to allow the computer in question free access for the rest of the day; regardless of who is actually using that computer.

Comment: But the idea as I understand it requires, at a minimum, hacking a different site's cookie. That's not exactly friendly. The way this is supposed to be done is by asking them to login to your site using facebook, or to have your site be a Facebook page that can see whether it has been liked by a specific user. What you're doing sounds like you want someone to share something as a payment to but site access, while cutting Facebook out of the interaction - they specifically don't want you to be able to do that.

Comment: But doesn't Facebook in fact provide a sharing service as `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=my_url_`? This is according to http://www.sitepoint.com/social-media-button-links/. The link I provides shows other social networks as well.

Comment: Yes, but all you can possibly do is see if that link was clicked - you can't see if they shared anything. If you want to enable something when they click the link, that's easy, but guarantees nothing.

Comment: If your "Share Me" link called a script, you could track that they clicked it, not necessarily that it was actually shared.  Alternatively, you could add a unique token to the URL so that you'd know when someone clicked the shared link.  You'd have to use server side magic to manage the results in the latter case, but if you truly must track whether your link is shared and/or clicked...